# How to display static files served from backend (ExpressJS) onto React Page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

I'm building a web app using React(frontend) and Node/Express(backend).
Now, I've stored some images in a 'public' folder(in the backend--express).
My goal is to fetch the images that are stored on the server and display them on my frontend page.
Sort of like when you fetch JSON data from the server/database, convert it to JSON and display the data onto the HTML page.

I'm using express.static() middleware to serve the images that are in the backend.
My problem is:

1. How do I send the images back to the frontend, and make them display onto the HTML page(React Component)?

Because when I use POSTMAN and make a request to the backend, the image displays in the body:
[image]

But whenever I make a request(using fetch) for a specific image in React, nothing shows on the page:
[image]

Here's my Express code[image]

My backend folder Structure:
[image]

Here's My React Code:

[image]

Comment: Why use fetch to get the image ? it’s an img file so just use the ‘img tag’

Comment: i want the images from the sever to show in the frontend    how do i do that?

Comment: What’s the response you get when your fetch the data

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code doesn't belong in images.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do fetch for image.
just add an image tag with  src as the path of the file like this :

`<img src="http://localhost:3000/GlobalSearch/ClubSearch/PlayerStats/Fisher.jpg" />`

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in other answers here that it is not advisable to use `fetch()` API for this purpose. I'll try to add a bit more context to this. Even I have been facing a very similar problem, the only difference being my frontend was in vanilla js and I was trying to display an HTML file.

The thing with `fetch()` is that, whenever you call some route using the `fetch()` API, then whatever you try to return through that route (in this case the static files) gets returned to your `fetch()` call. Now, `fetch()` does not have any in-built functionality to display anything on the frontend that has been sent to it.

Therefore the best bet is to not use `fetch()` at all for this purpose, and simply use the `<img />` tag. This should solve the problem.